# Is it possible to only have threads with the id an even number?

Tags: linux, multithreading, pthreads

I was doing some exercises with threads. In one such exercise a function ought to have different actions depending on the thread id. I got results as if all my threads were having as id's even numbers.

I tested separately using another variable, to which i gave both even and odd numbers, and it worked perfectly fine...

I was using `int x=pthread_self()` to get the thread id. Am I doing this wrong?

Comment: You are using it wrong. `pthread_self()` returns a `pthread_t`, not an `int`. `pthread_t` is not guaranteed to even be an arithmetic type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `pthread_t` type returned by `pthread_self()` is not guaranteed to even be a number (arithmetic type) at all - it could for example be a structure.

Even in the case where it is a number, it is entirely possible for it to always be an even number.  In fact, this *is* the case using the `glibc` implementation of pthreads, where the `pthread_t` is the base stack address of the thread - because stacks are always going to be page-aligned, they won't just be even, they'll in fact always be divisible by 4096.

If you want to have threads perform different actions depending on their thread ID, you are best off allocating your own sequential numeric thread IDs to threads yourself.

Answer (score 0):

It is perfectly correct Darkmer. The pthread_self() function returns the ID of the calling thread that you have created using pthread_create() function.

Answer (score 0):

No can't set pthread id and can't make any supposition about it. You have to create your own kind of id, like you probably already done, may be use pthread specific data?